# how can I create an incidence matrix in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

I would like to create an incidence matrix.
I have a file with 3 columns, like:

```
id x  y   
A  22   2   
B   4  21   
C  21 360   
D  26   2   
E  22  58   
F   2 347
```

And I want a matrix like (without col and row names):

```
  2 4 21 22 26 58 347 360   
A 1 0  0  1  0  0   0   0   
B 0 1  1  0  0  0   0   0   
C 0 0  1  0  0  0   0   1   
D 1 0  0  0  1  0   0   0   
E 0 0  0  1  0  1   0   0   
F 1 0  0  0  0  0   1   0
```

I have started the code like:

```
haps = readdlm("File.txt",header=true)      
hap1_2 = map(Int64,haps[1][:,2:end])    
ID = (haps[1][:,1])                      
dic1 = Dict()

for (i in 1:21)
    dic1[ID[i]] = hap1_2[i,:]
end

X=[zeros(21,22)];       #the original file has 21 rows and 22 columns 
X1 = hcat(ID,X)
```

The problem now is that I don't know how to fill the matrix with 1s in the specific columns as in the example above.
I'm also not sure if I'm on the right way.

Any suggestion that could help me??

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into the `ModelFrame()` and `ModelMatrix()` functions in the DataFrames package?  They may well have the functionality you need.  There is also the sparse() function for creating sparse matrices (which is what you're looking to create).  That would work here, but it's a bit more complicated to implement.

Comment: Is the identical column for x=2 and y=2 in the incidence matrix intentional?

Comment: It is much better for type-inference and efficiency to keep the incidence matrix of a single specific type, like Int or Bool, and not to mix in the labels which are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NamedArrays` is a neat package which allows naming both rows and columns and seems to fit the bill for this problem. Suppose the data is in `data.csv`, here is one method to go about it (install `NamedArrays` with `Pkg.add("NamedArrays")`):

```
data,header = readcsv("data.csv",header=true);
# get the column names by looking at unique values in columns
cols = unique(vec([(header[j+1],data[i,j+1]) for i in 1:size(data,1),j=1:2]))
# row names from ID column
rows = data[:,1]

using NamedArrays
narr = NamedArray(zeros(Int,length(rows),length(cols)),(rows,cols),("id","attr"));
# now stamp in the 1s in the right places
for r=1:size(data,1),c=2:size(data,2) narr[data[r,1],(header[c],data[r,c])] = 1 ; end
```

Now we have (note I transposed `narr` for better printout):

```
julia> narr'
10x6 NamedArray{Int64,2}:
attr ╲ id │ A  B  C  D  E  F
──────────┼─────────────────
("x",22)  │ 1  0  0  0  1  0
("x",4)   │ 0  1  0  0  0  0
("x",21)  │ 0  0  1  0  0  0
("x",26)  │ 0  0  0  1  0  0
("x",2)   │ 0  0  0  0  0  1
("y",2)   │ 1  0  0  1  0  0
("y",21)  │ 0  1  0  0  0  0
("y",360) │ 0  0  1  0  0  0
("y",58)  │ 0  0  0  0  1  0
("y",347) │ 0  0  0  0  0  1
```

But, if `DataFrames` are necessary, similar tricks should apply.

---------- UPDATE ----------

In case the column of a value should be ignored i.e. x=2 and y=2 should both set a 1 on column for value 2, then the code becomes:

```
using NamedArrays
data,header = readcsv("data.csv",header=true);
rows = data[:,1]
cols = map(string,sort(unique(vec(data[:,2:end]))))
narr = NamedArray(zeros(Int,length(rows),length(cols)),(rows,cols),("id","attr"));
for r=1:size(data,1),c=2:size(data,2) narr[data[r,1],string(data[r,c])] = 1 ; end
```

giving:

```
julia> narr
6x8 NamedArray{Int64,2}:
id ╲ attr │   2    4   21   22   26   58  347  360
──────────┼───────────────────────────────────────
A         │   1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
B         │   0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
C         │   0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
D         │   1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
E         │   0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
F         │   1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.      
The UPDATE version is what was looking for.      
Is there some way to print just the matrix, without the column and row names?       
Thanks!

Comment: NamedArrays are backed by regular arrays, which means, you can convert them to a regular Matrix with little overhead. Use: `array(narr)`.

Comment: You can also choose not to use NamedArrays and just stick with the `rows`, `cols` variables and make a regular Array. Use `narr = zeros(Int,length(rows),length(cols)`. The only tricky bit is finding the right column for filing the matrix. If you go this route you will need some sort of lookup table (or Dict).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight variation on something that I use for creating sparse matrices out of categorical variables for regression analyses.  The function includes a variety of comments and options to suit it to your needs.  Note: as written, it treats the appearances of "2" and "21" in x and y as separate.  It is far less elegant in naming and appearance than the nice response from Dan Getz.  The main advantage here is that it works with sparse matrices so if your data is huge, this will be helpful in reducing storage space and computation time.

```
function OneHot(x::Array, header::Bool)
    UniqueVals = unique(x)
    Val_to_Idx = [Val => Idx for (Idx, Val) in enumerate(unique(x))] ## create a dictionary that maps unique values in the input array to column positions in the new sparse matrix.
    ColIdx = convert(Array{Int64}, [Val_to_Idx[Val] for Val in x])
    MySparse = sparse(collect(1:length(x)),  ColIdx, ones(Int32, length(x)))
    if header
        return [UniqueVals' ; MySparse]  ## note: this won't be sparse
        ## alternatively use return (MySparse, UniqueVals) to get a tuple, second element is the header which you can then feed to something to name the columns or do whatever else with
    else
        return MySparse ## use MySparse[:, 2:end] to drop a value (which you would want to do for categorical variables in a regression)
    end
end

x = [22, 4, 21, 26, 22, 2];
y = [2, 21, 360, 2, 58, 347];

Incidence = [OneHot(x, true) OneHot(y, true)]

7x10 Array{Int64,2}:
 22  4  21  26  2  2  21  360  58  347
  1  0   0   0  0  1   0    0   0    0
  0  1   0   0  0  0   1    0   0    0
  0  0   1   0  0  0   0    1   0    0
  0  0   0   1  0  1   0    0   0    0
  1  0   0   0  0  0   0    0   1    0
  0  0   0   0  1  0   0    0   0    1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
The only problem is that I would like to not have duplicate values in the first row ( like 2 2 ).

Comment: @GersonOliveiraJunior Ok, sure thing, no worries.  It looks like the solution from Dan gets more at what you're looking for.  This is just a snipptet of code I had from another project and figured I'd throw it out there in case it was useful.