# How to create a incidence matrix in Julia Dataframes

Tags: dataframe, matrix, jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

going on with my studies I am struggling to find a way to create incidence matrices.
I found that "solution" [how-can-i-create-an-incidence-matrix-in-julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797937/how-can-i-create-an-incidence-matrix-in-julia) but I do neither fully understand nor is the solution still operable

If we have some simple Dataframe like

```
df = DataFrame(Lines = (1:20), From = rand(1:10,20), To = rand(1:10,20))
```

[image: df]

Now I would like to convert that Dataframe into an incidence matrix consisting only of "0", "1" (Starting Point), and "-1" (Endpoint). It should look like this (except their should be 1 and -1 in the matrix...but i do not how to do so...)

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1) Do you want a data frame or a matrix as an output? 2) what des the `:Lines` column mean in your input data frame? 3) what should be done if: 3a) there are multiple directed edges, 3b) if there are edges in both ways?

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński From what I understand of incident matrices, the `Lines` represent the edges of the graph, and should become the columns of the output incidence matrix. If there are multiple directed edges, or edges both ways, those will be represented in the input df as separate rows already (for eg. rows 5 and 19 here), and should become separate columns in the output. It's basically two-hot encoding of the input, with the first column's values becoming the column numbers, second column encoded as the `1` position and the third column encoded as the position containing `-1`.

Comment: Ah - sorry. I have mixed up adjacency and incidence matrix. What you ask for is a transpose of incidence matrix (typically in rows you get nodes). I will propose how to do it.

Comment: One more comment - how would you want self-loops to be indicated?

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński (note that I'm not the original poster, so the transpose may be my fault - that's the kind of incidence matrix I was taught.)

Comment: At least in standard internet references like https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncidenceMatrix.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix edges are put in columns.

Comment: Thanks for your help and  I will elaborate on the question. This particular question is based on an electricity grid. So the Lines are power lines and the values in columns "from" and "to" represent buses (e.g. Line "1" goes from Bus "3" to Bus "7". This should become some teaching material. In power grid analysis you first need to calculate your incidence matrix which afterwards will be expanded to the (already mentioned) adjacence matrix...this will be the next step ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(Lines = (1:20), From = rand(1:10,20), To = rand(1:10,20))
20×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Lines  From   To    
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      4      9
   2 │     2      3      8
   3 │     3      9      1
   4 │     4      3      9
   5 │     5      4      1
   6 │     6      9      8
   7 │     7      3      4
   8 │     8      8      2
   9 │     9      3      7
  10 │    10      6      5
  11 │    11      7      9
  12 │    12      8      9
  13 │    13      8      6
  14 │    14      9      3
  15 │    15      3      6
  16 │    16      5     10
  17 │    17      3      1
  18 │    18      8      5
  19 │    19      2      9
  20 │    20      5      6

julia> let imat = zeros(Int, nrow(df), max(maximum(df.From), maximum(df.To))) # assuming nodes start being numbered from 1
           for (i, (from, to)) in enumerate(zip(df.From, df.To))
               imat[i, from] = 1
               imat[i, to] = -1
           end
           res = DataFrame(imat, Symbol.(axes(imat, 2)))
           insertcols!(res, 1, :Lines => df.Lines)
       end
20×11 DataFrame
 Row │ Lines  1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10    
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │     1      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0     -1      0
   2 │     2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0     -1      0      0
   3 │     3     -1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
   4 │     4      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0     -1      0
   5 │     5     -1      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
   6 │     6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     -1      1      0
   7 │     7      0      0      1     -1      0      0      0      0      0      0
   8 │     8      0     -1      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0
   9 │     9      0      0      1      0      0      0     -1      0      0      0
  10 │    10      0      0      0      0     -1      1      0      0      0      0
  11 │    11      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0     -1      0
  12 │    12      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1     -1      0
  13 │    13      0      0      0      0      0     -1      0      1      0      0
  14 │    14      0      0     -1      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
  15 │    15      0      0      1      0      0     -1      0      0      0      0
  16 │    16      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0     -1
  17 │    17     -1      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  18 │    18      0      0      0      0     -1      0      0      1      0      0
  19 │    19      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0     -1      0
  20 │    20      0      0      0      0      1     -1      0      0      0      0
```

In the solution I used `let` to ensure that the operation is fast.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way is by using broadcasting:

```
inci=zeros(Int,20,10)
setindex!.(Ref(inci), 1, df.Lines, df.From)
setindex!.(Ref(inci), -1, df.Lines, df.To)
```

This yields a `Matrix` that of course can be converted to a DataFrame whenever needed:

```
julia> inci
20×10 Matrix{Int64}:
  0  -1   0   0   1   0   0   0  0   0
  0   0   0   0   0   1   0  -1  0   0
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1  1   0
  0  -1   0   0   0   0   0   1  0   0
  0   0   0  -1   0   0   1   0  0   0
  0   1  -1   0   0   0   0   0  0   0
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  1  -1
  0   1  -1   0   0   0   0   0  0   0
  0   0   1   0  -1   0   0   0  0   0
  0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0  0   0
 -1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0  0   0
  1   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0  0   0
  0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0  1   0
  1   0   0   0  -1   0   0   0  0   0
 -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0   1
  0   0   0  -1   0   0   0   0  0   1
  0   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0  0   1
  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0  0  -1
  0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0  0   0
  0   0  -1   0   0   0   0   1  0   0
```